# Maven compile with compiler option --add-exports

Tags: java, maven, javac, java-15

So I finally switched to Java 15, and found out that my old code is not compiling anymore.
I use classes from package `sun.jvmstat.monitor` and class `LocalVmManager` to retrieve the pid of all JVM running in the system: this is working on Java8, but no more on Java15 (I think it doesn't work since Java9).

Thanks to IntelliJ I discovered that I need to pass the following options to `javac`: `--add-exports jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.perfdata.monitor.protocol.local=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor.event=ALL-UNNAMED`

And in fact with this options I'm able to compile via command line. But I also wanted to compile my application via `mvn compile`. **How can I specify options to compiler in the pom.xml ?**

I tried the following with no luck:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>15</release>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                    <arg>jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.perfdata.monitor.protocol.local=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                    <arg>jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                    <arg>jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor.event=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In the meantime I'm going to change my code and read the pid of running JVMs by scanning the `/proc/` directory.

Comment: As [is documented](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs), `<compilerArgs>` as you have them written will work. Can you edit your question to explain further what isn't working?  Finally, if 9 is your baseline https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#pid() is the simple way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I have good news for you, you don't need `LocalVmManager` anymore. This will do for your current JVM:

```java
ProcessHandle.current().pid()
```

To access the PIDs of other processes:

```java
ProcessHandle
    // returns Stream<ProcessHandle>
    .allProcesses()
    .filter(/* filter to only find JVM processes */)
    .map(ProcessHandle::pid)
    .collect(toList());
```

[The `ProcessHandle` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) was added in Java 9 and gives you a lot of information about OS processes - check [the method `info()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#info()) as well. :)

Comment: Not what I've asked for

Comment: I overlooked that you needed the PIDs of all JVM processes - just added that to the answer. I know you asked for access to `LocalVmManager`, but given there's a supported API, you should not used internals. There's no guarantee they work in other JVMs/OSs or even on your JVM/OS in the next minor release.

Comment: My comment was to your first answer where you only replied how to retrieve current process pid

Comment: Makes sense. Once you've tried this and it works, I'll delete my end of this conversation because it doesn't add anything and may indeed be confusing to later visitors.